# Azure で REST API を作成したい

Tags: api, azure, rest

こんにちは
私は Azure で RESTfulなAPI を作成したいです。
その方法は
•ローカルで REST API 作成後、AzureAppServiceに発行する
•AzureDataFactoryを使用する

があると考えています。
これらで実現は可能ですか？
もしくは他の方法がありますか？
ご協力ありがとう。

Answer (score 0):

最も簡単な方法はAzure Logic Appsを使ってGUIだけで簡単なAPIを作る事だと思います。

次にAzureFunctionsを使う方法が、環境を考えないでもいいので簡単に作れます。